# how to implement javascript in uiwebview for pdf file implementation?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ipad, pdf, uiwebview

I am trying to implement pdf annotation with ipad using uiwebview. I am able to load the pdf file but i am not able to use the functions. I felt that i am able to use javascript with uiwebview and implement the things,but then found saying that javascript is not available for pdf file.
 http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/01/12/search-and-highlight-text-in-uiwebview/comment-page-3/#comment-7600

Can you help me with some solution if possible. I am now really in need of some solutions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, you can't do anything about PDF shown in a `UIWebView`.

You need to work hard parsing PDF files and manipulating it.

Comment: Okay..but can you show me some other direction? I really am in an awkward box

Comment: No, you just can't do anything inside the UIWebView. You need to read the PDF specification and work hard. Or buy the PDF annotator code from the people making GoodReader, if they sell their UIKit views.